# Lenovo touchpad issues on 710S, and settung global play / stop button for media

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, synaptics

I recently switched from a Mac to Ubuntu, having now a Lenovo 710S-13ISK.
So far so good, everything is working but some touchpad issues where I therefore ask here for help.
The tap to click (also with two fingers) and vertical two finger scrolling is working.

1. The horizontal scrolling, which is incredibly useful when browsing and therefore switching back and forth of pages, is not working.
2. The zooming / rotating with two fingers is not working.
3. more than 2 finger gestures are not working.
4. I wonder is there a way to set up hotkeys for play / stop / next media / previous media if the keyboard doesn't provide such keys? This would be useful to manage the playing of videos or songs in a comfortable way.

Could you help please me to get the issues working?
And do you know where I can set up gestures for 3+ finger gestures?

I would be very grateful for any help.
Thank you very much,

Tobias

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Is libinput installed? It has horizontal scrolling. Other gestures can be set by touchegg. But the DE should support them. Zooming is not.